# Touchpad doesn't work coorectly after update to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, 16.04

I was using 14.04 Ubuntu version before and I did reverse my click because I'm a left-hand user.

In 14.04 when i reverse my click, my touchpad tap doesn't get reversed, that's what i want but When I tap the touchpad after 16.04 update, it does get reversed too.

I am using HP 14g-105Au. I have contact the support but they don't support any Linux OS for this kind of laptop.

Is there any good idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Set Synclient to TapButton1=1

you may want to check before making changes

```
synclient -l | grep TapButton
```

---

To set :

```
synclient TapButton1=0
```

I put a bash script in /usr/bin/ and add this script to startup applications. You just need to use **chmod** to tell the system is an executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TapButton2=0;
```